# Cannot get encode caret ^ symbol in the url

Tags: reactjs, url, urlencode, encodeuricomponent, malformedurlexception

I have a problem to get encoding the caret **^** symbol in the URL. The console log error messages are `URIError: URI malformed`. I am using the `encodeURIComponent` function to encode the data in the URL. After I use `history.push` the pathname. Below is my sample code:

companyName value is `Test Character )(*&(^&%^%$#@)(`
code value is `Test Character Branch !@#$@%^&`

```html
const selectRow = async (code, companyName, e) => {
    const encodedCompanyName = encodeURIComponent(companyName);
    const encodedCode = encodeURIComponent(code);
    console.log("encodedCompanyName:" + encodedCompanyName + "encodedCode:" +encodedCode );
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push({
      pathname: `/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=${encodedCompanyName}&branchName=${encodedCode}`,
    });
  };
```

So the console.log results are:

```html
encodedCompanyName:Test%20Character%20)(*%26(%5E%26%25%5E%25%24%23%40)(encodedCode:Test%20Character%20Branch%20!%40%23%24%40%25%5E%26
```

So when I want to get Parameter and URL, the URL's parameters encode values not the same as the above console log value. Below are my get parameter functions.

```html
export const getParameterByName = (name, url = window.location.href) => {
  name = name.replace(/[\]]/g, "\\$&");
  console.log("URL:" + url);
  var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
  
  if (!results) return null;

  if (!results[2]) return "";

  return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
};
```

Above console log URL values are: `URL:http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=Test%20Character%20)(*%26(^%26%^%24%23%40)(&branchName=Test%20Character%20Branch%20!%40%23%24%40%^%26`

I have checked the above URL values are not the same as what I encode code and companyName.

I want the expected results are `http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=Test%20Character%20)(*%26(%5E%26%25%5E%25%24%23%40)(&branchName=Test%20Character%20Branch%20!%40%23%24%40%25%5E%26`

Comparison:

```html
Wrong URL in console log: 
http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=Test%20Character%20)(*%26(^%26%^%24%23%40)(&branchName=Test%20Character%20Branch%20!%40%23%24%40%^%26

Wrong URL in browser: 
http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=Test%20Character%20)(*%26(^%26%^%%24%23%40)(&branchName=Test%20Character%20Branch%20!%40%23%24%40%^%26

Expected correct URL:

http://localhost:3005/branch-management/edit-branch/?companyName=Test%20Character%20)(*%26(%5E%26%25%5E%25%24%23%40)(&branchName=Test%20Character%20Branch%20!%40%23%24%40%25%5E%26
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem or can give me sample make it caret **^** can decode well. Thanks.